# AC converter with MOSFETs

Tags: mosfet, ac, converter

For this AC-AC converter circuit:

[image]

and these VGS signals:

[image]

I would like to know how the current flows through the circuit when the FET1 is OFF.

These are the output signals - VDS1 and VDS2:

[image]

It shows that when FET1 is OFF, FET2 is ON.
It can't go D2, D3, back source, because the circuit is open.

If FET1 is OFF, how does the current get back to the AC source?

Comment: What’s wrong with the original question on this matter https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/575843/ac-ac-converter-with-pwm-circuit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When FET1 is off current does not get back to the AC source.

Instead FET2 will be turned on and the current that is flowing in the inductor continues to flow until the magnetic field subsides.

It flows though FET2 and the diodes around it then back to the bottom of the inductor.

It is basically a buck converter with bridge rectifiers around the FETs so it can operate from AC.